# how can i redirect dynamic URL in worpress base on ID in htaccess or wp-config or function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect 301 to the below URL

worpress.com/NewsInfoPrint?id=13624

to

wordpress.com/news/13624/

// number is ID post in WordPress and  I need for all posts to do that, so the number is dynamic

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^\/NewsInfoPrint$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \/news/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Aghilan B. I  put this code in the first line in htaccess and works. good luck to you